# What does this macro mean #define div_ac_power(y,x) *y/x

Tags: c

```
#define div_ac_power(y,x)           *y/x
```

Shall y be an address? As far as I understand it returns the result of division between a pointer (y) and whatever object is x.

Comment: That macro is badly written. Think about something like `div_ac_power(a + 1, 5 -b)`? Macro arguments should always be parenthesised and the macro replacement text itself, too (unless it has highest preceedence). Or, better: do not use a macro here, but an inline function. That avoids all these problems plus type-safety.

Comment: Please show how the macro is used.

Answer (score 3):

> As far as I understand it returns the result of division between a pointer (y) and whatever object is x.

That is probably the intention.

The macro needs more parenthesis to secure it from misuse.

Consider the following cases:

Case 1. Compound parameter:

```
result= div_ac_power(y,a+b);
```

which is expanded to:

```
result = *y/a+b; // This equals (*y/a)+b because of operator precedence.
```

Case 2. Fooling around:

```
result= a div_ac_power(y,b); // Note the lack of operator between a and macro
```

which is expanded to:

```
result= a*y/b; // This may well be a valid expression depending on the types of a, b, y.
```

To fix it, you could add parenthesis:

```
#define div_ac_power(y,x)           (*(y)/(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Dereference the value pointed-to by `y` pointer
2. Divide this value by `x` value

Same as:

```
int *y, x; // init them
int z = *y;
int res = z / x;
```

Comment: This is the probable intention of the code, but it varies on usage. `*` can be both a unary dereference or a binary multiplication depending on context, which is why parenthesis is important in macros.

Comment: @GeirGrusom If it is really binary multiply, I would say that code is very bad.